# How to remove hidden quotes on numbers in excel that prevent changing the format

Tags: excel, number-formatting

I have copied several columns of data with ~85 rows from a webpage system that my company uses. One column of numbers copied over with no issues, but the other (and more important) column contains hidden quotes surrounding the numbers. I cannot change format, nor add the numbers, etc.

I have tried using =value(mid(cell,1,len(cell)-1)) to remove the quotes, and have also tried using substitute, with no success.

Does anyone know of another possible solution to try?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the data look like? What is the expected, and actual, output?

Comment: I think this may be down to the type of content.. Try changing via formatting right click cell(s)>Number tab ... General to Number...

Comment: The data consists of account numbers (which copy fine) and dollar amounts (which contain the quotes). Any attempt to add, etc. any of the dollar amounts results in a #Value error. The numbers appear as "98,518.78 " when I use the 'Evaluate Formula' function

Comment: @JGFMK, it will not allow me to change the format. The numbers appear normal in the formula bar, I can only see the quotes around them when I use 'Evaluate Formula'

Comment: Try something like this in B1.. =VALUE(TRIM(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2))) - that's assuming quotes are visible at start/end of cell A1

Comment: You should be able to change the format - depending on the value, the format may not change though. What happens if you try `LEFT(cell, 1)`? Do you get the quote?

Comment: It may be that len-1 should be len-2...

Comment: When I use the TRIM formula, it keeps the quotes and trims the numbers within them

Comment: I got it to work using =VALUE(TRIM(A1,1,LEN(A1),-2)))...Thanks!

Comment: `Text to columns` may also work.

Comment: An alternative would be to copy/paste the column to a text file in Notepad++ (or your preferred editor), remove the " (replace all with ""), and then copy again in a clean column in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Saw the file as csv format. Close it and reopen in csv. It will show all the hidden quotations. Then use text to column and remove the special characters.